# doctrine query in model or controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter, orm, doctrine

I'm using Codeigniter and Doctrine together for a project.  I've gotten everything set up with both of these tools.  But I'm not sure where I should have this bit of code:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM sessions u');
$sessions = $query->getResult(); // array of User objects
```

Should I be putting this in the controller or in the models/entities?  At first thought, I figured I should put this kind of logic in the Sessions model, but it requires the entities manager $em, which I had thought should have been in the controller.

Thanks, this has been driving me crazy for the past half hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of people like to create objects called DAOs or Data Access Objects to store this type of information.

The DAO contains the entity manager and methods that can be called and return the data you need. For example this function would reside in a DAO:

```
function findEmployeeById($emp_id)
```

And it would contain the query used to retrieve an employee from the database. In your controller you would just use the DAO instead of having an entity manager and dealing with it at that level.

But it really depends on preference and how large your project is.

Comment: Where would I put something like that (DAO) in codeigniter?  in the models, or as part of a library?

Comment: I am not very familiar with codeigniter but I would probably put it with the model.